# How do you print instance names?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to print the names of a few objects in an array. They're all instances of a class called StockHolding and are named stock1, stock2, and stock3. I can't figure out how to get NSLog to print the actual names of these instances, though. Instead it prints out the name of the class the instances belong to and a memory address (e.g., "2013-12-12 21:06:05.782 Stocks[18093:303] Stock <StockHolding: 0x100106410> was worth 2.30 when you bought it. It's now worth 4.50. You have 40 shares of it."). I want it to print "Stock stock1 was worth..." How do I get NSLog to print out the name of the instances in the array? Code snippet below:

```
    NSMutableArray *myStocks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
    [myStocks addObject:stock1];
    [myStocks addObject:stock2];
    [myStocks addObject:stock3];
    for (StockHolding *s in myStocks) {
        NSLog(@"Stock %@ was worth %.02f when you bought it. It's now worth %.02f. You have %d shares of it.", s, s.purchaseSharePrice, s.currentSharePrice, s.numberOfShares);
    }
```

Comment: The variable names don't exist at runtime. All you have are pointers, no names.

Comment: You can define 1 NSString property, assign values as stock1, stock2 and than print they

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The names `stock1`, `stock2`, and `stock3` don't belong to those objects; they belong to the variables that you've put those objects into.

Even that's not quite right. The variables hold pointers; you put a pointer to each object into each variable.

Think of the object as a balloon; the pointer is the string by which you keep hold of the object. If you don't tie that pointer to anything, or if you untie it, the object flies away. The variables are cleats to which you tie the balloons' strings, and the balloons remain in your possession as long as the variables exist and the balloons are tied down to them.

You can tie a single string to multiple posts. You can assign the same object('s pointer) to multiple variables:

```
stock1 = [[StockHolding alloc] init]; //Or something
stock2 = stock1;
stock3 = stock2;
```

After that last line, what's the name of the object?

Nothing. It doesn't have one. Or if it does have a `name` property, it hasn't changed, because none of these lines sets that property.

What those lines do is tie the one StockHolding's string to three different posts: all three variables—the variables named `stock1`, `stock2`, and `stock3`—now point to the same object.

Answer (score 4):

Implement the `description` method to return whatever string you want describing the instance.   Very very useful for debugging purposes.   Should not be used for displaying strings to the user.

The `description` method is documented as a part of the [`NSObject` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/description).

By doing that, then `NSLog(@"array %@", array)` will include the description of all objects in the array as determined by your implementation of `description`.

Comment: Yes, what the OP presumably wants is a way to easily print the name of the stock.  Implementing `description` to simply return whatever internal variable contains the stock name would do this quite simply.

Comment: And if a StockHolding currently doesn't have a stock name for `description` to return, then that's also on the questioner's to-do list: add a `name` property.